# Normal extensions (a question about the definition)

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

The definition of a normal extension in the book "Abstract algebra" is :

> If $K$ is an algebric extension of $F$ which is the splitting field over $F$ for a collection of polynomials $f(x)\in F[x]$ then $K$ is called a normal extension

I think that there is something here I don't understand: If $K$ is an algebraic extension of $F$ then by definition each element of $K$ is a root of a polynimial with coefficients in $F$.

So each element of $K$ corresponds to a polynomial in $F[x]$ (s.t the element is a root of this polynomial).

So I deduced that $K$ is the splitiing field of the collections of polynomials in $F[x]$ that corresponds to the elements in $K$. Hence every algebric extension is also a normal one.

What part of my argument is wrong ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just because the extension contains a root of a polynomial doesn't mean that it contains *all* of the roots of the polynomial, which is a requirement for it to be the splitting field for the polynomial.

For example, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ is not normal because it is not the splitting field of the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[3]{2}$, namely $x^3-2$.  This can be seen through Theorem 13 on p. 572 in Dummit and Foote:

[image]

If $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ were the splitting field for some polynomial (which doesn't split in $\mathbb{Q}$) then it would be the splitting field for any irreducible factor of that polynomial.  In a field of characteristic $0$ (e.g. $\mathbb{Q}$), every irreducible polynomial is separable.  So, by the theorem, since $x^3-2$ has a root in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$, it would split in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ if the extension were normal.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ is not normal because it is not the splitting field of *any collection* of polynomials...

Comment: @lhf thanks, I have clarified the answer.

Comment: It's been a long time since the question was answered but I don't understand the proof of the Theorem that @AntonioVargas posted from that book. I don't understand the step where they apply the induction hypothesis. Could you explain that proof to me, please?

Comment: @Kits89 it would probably be best to open a new question about that.