# One root of an irreducible polynomial in an extension field, so is the other.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $E$ be an extension of $\mathbb Z_p$ contained in an algebraic closure $\bar{\mathbb Z_p}$. Let $f$ be an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb Z_p[x]$ and let $a, b \in \bar{\mathbb Z_p}$ be roots of $f$. If $a\in E$, show that $b\in E$.

Comment: Do you mean $\,\Bbb Z_p=\Bbb F_p=\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z\;$ ?

Comment: This is true if $E/\mathbb Z_p$ is Galois.  See [my answer here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/140307/5531).

Comment: @AntonioVargas, it is true *always*: any finite extension of a finite field is always Galois.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

Any finite field $\,\Bbb F_{p^n}\;$ is the splitting field of $\,p_n(x):=x^{p^n}-x\in\Bbb F_p\,$ , which means that field is the set of all the roots (in some algebraic closure of the prime field $\,\Bbb F_p\,$) of $\,p_n(x)\,$ .

Now, suppose $\,E=\Bbb F_{p^m}\;$ and suppose further $\;\deg f=n\;$ :

$$a\in \Bbb F_p(a)\cong\Bbb F_{p^n}  \;$$

and since this last is the *minimal* field containing both $\,\Bbb F_p\,$ and $\,a\,$ then $\,F_{p^n}\le E\,$ .

But then both $\,p_n(x)\;,\;f(x)\;$ have $\,a\,$ as a root , so

$$f(x)\mid p_n(x)\;\;(\text{why?})\implies p_n(x)=f(x)g(x)$$

and the above means **all** the roots of $\,f(x)\,$ are also roots of $\,p_n(x)\,$ , so also $\,b\in \Bbb F_{p^n}\le E\;$ and we're done.

Note the above is far from being true for general fields...

Comment: Thanks. But I don't know why $f(x)\mid p_n(x)$. Would you mind giving me other hints?

Comment: @Rose, remember that if *the minimal pol.* of an algebraic element over some field always divides any **other** polynomial that vanishes on that element...and your $\,f\,$ is **a** minimal pol. of $\,a\,$ , though it must be monic to be **the** minimal pol.